# extend to the end of Monday vs to the end of the day Monday vs to Monday

Tags: grammar, word-choice, american-english, informal-language

I'd like to ask my teacher if she can extend the due date for an assignment, which I was supposed to hand in by the beginning(?) of Monday, to Monday 11:59 pm.
Which one is correct?
Is there a better way to say this?

> Could you extend the due date to the end of Monday?
>   Could you extend the due date to the end of the day Monday?
>   Could you extend the due date to Monday?

Comment: You are really going to "hand it in" at 11:59 PM? If not, maybe you should use "turn it in", which means submit by any means. And "end-of-day" refers to the end of the business day or activities on that date, not necessarily 11:59 PM.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the **due date** is already Monday, so you are asking for an extension of time on the due date.

> extend the due date to Monday

is incorrect in your example, since the **due date** is already Monday.

> end of the day Monday

may mean the end of business-day Monday, which is not what you want.

> end of Monday

is closer to what you mean. However, to avoid ambiguity, teachers will usually specify

> due by midnight on Monday

So you would be asking for an extension until 1 minute before midnight, which is essentially midnight.  In the current age of electronic assignment submissions, it can be easily enforced.

If your teacher only specified "Monday", you would have a valid argument that midnight is still a valid time to submit your assignment.

Answer (score 1):

It's not idiomatically correct to say "extend the due date": it's a date which, like a number, is inherently not extensible.

You can **change** or [delay](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/delay?q=Delay://) or [defer](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/defer://) the due date, but taken literally that would only mean changing to a different day.

You can deal with both of these issues by using [deadline](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/deadline?q=Deadline://) rather than due date.

> Could you extend the deadline until midnight?